# Bind ScrollBar of GridView to end of screen

Tags: android, gridview

How do I change the position of `ScrollBar` in `GridView`?

it is binded to items position in my case:

[image]

and there's free space between last item and `ScrollBar`. And this scroll overlaps with item. I need to save the `paddingRight` for items but not for `ScrollBar`.

How can I do this?

**gridview .xml**:

```
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="tenkol.design.com.imbrecords.FragmentChannelsUkr"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <GridView android:id="@+id/gridView_ua"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout >
```

**gridview item .xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <tenkol.design.com.imbrecords.SquaredImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_channelIcon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

---

current (see ScrollBar overlaps with images):

[image]

expected:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the current and expected result through image.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin, please check my edit. I just want to make proper paddings/margins to right of items but can't realize how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself:

removed paddings in layout so gridview takes full screen:

```
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="tenkol.design.com.imbrecords.FragmentChannelsUkr"
android:background="@color/white">

<GridView android:id="@+id/gridView_ua"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout >
```

and added paddings to my `SquaredImageView`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
    setPadding(16,16,16,16);//Snap to width
}
```